# Why font awesome icon \f105 is not appears?

Tags: bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I am using a breadcrumb BS4 like this (fa latest version)

```css
.breadcrumb > li + li:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\f105';
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

but > icon is not appears... When I used previous version of font-awesome, it works perfectly. Can someone tell me the solution

Comment: Most likely you're either using the wrong font family, which is "Font Awesome 5 Free" for the free version, or something wrong with your import of the stylesheet

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at this; your issue should be because of the font-family your using, which should be `Font Awesome 5 Free` for the free version, or `Font Awesome 5 Pro` for the Pro version.

Font weight also needs to be `900` on the free version since those are the only icons that can be used.

```css
.breadcrumb li {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.breadcrumb li:before {
  content: '\f105';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="breadcrumb">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation... Actually I used font-weight:normal, this was the problem